# "ImportError: cannot import name '_gi'" error despite having python3-gi package installed

Tags: python, libraries

I am running the following bitbake command

```
bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig
```

and I'm getting the following error

```
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi'
```

From what I have seen online, installing `python3-gi` worked for some but for me it's already installed.